# Compare elements within a list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, tuples

```
List = [('j100', 'Jacob'), ('k150', 'Kevin'), ('d120', 'Davis'), ('d120', 'Davies'), ('c642', 'Charles'), ('s315', 'Stephen')]
```

I have this list of tuples and I want to make a nested loop to compare the first elements of the tuples together, to see if they are the same. so I want to compare j100 with k150 to see if they are the same etc. for all the elements.

Then I want to create a line of output if they are the same so d120=d120 I want the output to be  "Davies and Davis have similar sounding names." and Davies and davis have to be in alphabetical order.

how would I construct something like this?

Comment: Try to break your problem in small pieces. How to compare two elements of a list at the same time? Use a nested for loop on the same list. How to iterate on a list of tuples? Unpack the elements in the for loop like `for a, b in list_of_2_tuples:`. How to sort a list of tuples? Try `sorted` with a custom `key` argument.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a list comprehension to do this concisely:

```
lst = [('j100', 'Jacob'), ('k150', 'Kevin'), ('d120', 'Davis'), ('d120', 'Davies'), ('c642', 'Charles'), ('s315', 'Stephen')]

[print(f'{i[1]} and {l[1]} have similar sounding names') for i in lst for j in lst if i[1] != j[1] and i[0] == j[0]]
```

Output:

```
Davis and Davies have similar sounding names
Davies and Davis have similar sounding names
```

This does it for every combination. You could break this down to a more readable loop and account for the doubles if you do not want them like so:

```
lst = [('j100', 'Jacob'), ('k150', 'Kevin'), ('d120', 'Davis'), ('d120', 'Davies'), ('c642', 'Charles'), ('s315', 'Stephen')]

seen = []
for i in lst:
    for j in lst:
        if i[1] != j[1] and i[0] == j[0]:
            setij = {i[1], j[1]}
            if setij not in seen:
                seen.append(setij)
                print(f'{i[1]} and {j[1]} have similar sounding names')
```

Output:

```
Davis and Davies have similar sounding names
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dict` to group together names with the same tag:

```py
List = [('j100', 'Jacob'), ('k150', 'Kevin'), ('d120', 'Davis'), ('d120', 'Davies'), ('c642', 'Charles'), ('s315', 'Stephen')]

sim = {}
for item in List:
    key,name = item
    if key in sim:
        sim[key].append(name)
    else:
        sim[key]=[name]


for _,names in sim.items():
    if len(names) > 1:
        names.sort()
        print(f'{" and ".join(names)} have similar sounding names.')
```

Output

```
Davies and Davis have similar sounding names.
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified input:

```
List = [('d120', 'Davi'), ('j100', 'Jacob'), ('k150', 'Kevin'), ('d120', 'Davis'), ('d120', 'Davies'), ('c642', 'Charles'), ('s315', 'Stephen')]
```

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby, combinations
from operator import itemgetter

for _, group in groupby(sorted(List), key=itemgetter(0)):
    group = [name for _, name in group]
    if len(group) > 1:
        print(" and ".join(group) + " have similar sounding names.")
```

Output:

```
Davi and Davies and Davis have similar sounding names.
```

If you want pairwise ouput then you could try this with [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
for _, group in groupby(sorted(List), key=itemgetter(0)):
    group = [name for _, name in group]
    if len(group) > 1:
        for name1, name2 in combinations(group, 2):
            print(f"{name1} and {name2} have similar sounding names.")
```

Output:

```
Davi and Davies have similar sounding names.
Davi and Davis have similar sounding names.
Davies and Davis have similar sounding names.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
List = [('j100', 'Jacob'), ('k150', 'Kevin'), ('d120', 'Davis'), ('d120', 'Davies'), ('c642', 'Charles'), ('s315', 'Stephen')]

for a in range(len(List)-1):
    a_item = List[a]
    for b in range(a+1,len(List)):
        b_item = List[b]
        
        if a_item[0] == b_item[0]:
            result = [a_item[1],b_item[1]]
            result.sort()
            print(f'{result[0]} and {result[1]} have similar sounding names.')
```